# If n=15 and the standard deviation is known, do I use the t-test or the z-test or chi-squared test?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am testing my null hypothesis of $\mu=3$ against the alternative of $\mu >3$.  $n=16$ and $\sigma=1$ and $\alpha=0.10$.

I am conflicted because it is a small sample size and I know the standard deviation.  How do I decide which test to use given only this information?  I initially solved with the t-test, but I am reading that you should not use it if you know the standard deviation.

Comment: If you know the true (i.e. not sample) standard deviation, the z-test is more powerful

Comment: @user217285 Okay. So it is the sample standard deviation.  Therefore, I should go ahead with the t-test?

Comment: Well, you said $\sigma = 1$ -- people typically reserve that notation for the true standard deviation (as opposed to $\hat sigma$ or $\hat s$), so z-test is better.